# .htaccess redirect inside subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I found the following rewrite to use on my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

it works perfectly in the root directory, but I can't seem to get it to work in a subfolder.  I have also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^Social_Network/user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ Social_Network/user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/Social_Network/user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /Social_Network/user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

but neither seem to work.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/Social_Network/user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

I have included the entire file incase there are any other problems effecting this line.

Comment: no.  I'm not sure if each folder needs a separate .htaccess file, or if that is a good idea... I'll give it a try, but I would prefer to have one common file with all rules.

Comment: If there is only one .htaccess in root then `RewriteRule ^Social_Network/user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ Social_Network/user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]` will work fine.

Comment: In researching the problem, I found I need to add some lines for godaddy... I think when I added the lines I introduced an error somewhere, because I just tried again, and anubhava you are right, that solution does work now.  Thanks.

Comment: What lines did you add for GoDaddy?

Answer (score 0):

Just closing the question.
In researching the problem, I found I need to add some lines for godaddy... I think when I added the lines I introduced an error somewhere, because I just tried again, and anubhava you are right, that solution does work now. Thanks. –